# Annotations in custom Eclipse text editor don't show up

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to write a custom text editor with a reconciler that will update the AST and create markers for the errors, if there are any. I managed to add markers that show up in the left ruler of the editor and in the problems view. However, I also want those errors to be underlined in the text. That doesn't work. None of the text is underlined. If I double click on one of the errors in the problem view however, the corresponding text in the text editor is selected. As far as I understand, I need to add an annotation in addition to the marker. This is what I have tried so far:

```
final IResource resource = ResourceUtil.getResource(getEditorInput());
final IMarker marker = resource.createMarker("com.test.myproblemmarker");
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "hello");
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, 2);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, 10);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);

final IDocumentProvider idp = getDocumentProvider();
final IDocument document = idp.getDocument(getEditorInput());
final IAnnotationModel iamf = idp.getAnnotationModel(getEditorInput());

final SimpleMarkerAnnotation ma = new SimpleMarkerAnnotation("org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.error", marker);
ma.setText("hello");

iamf.connect(document);
iamf.addAnnotation(ma, new Position(2, 8));
ma.update();
iamf.disconnect(document);
ma.update();
```

The relevant parts from `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension id="com.test.problemmarker" point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers" name="A Problem">
    <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker"/>
    <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"/>
    <persistent value="true"/>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification" id="myannotationspecification" name="MyAnnotation">
    <specification
      annotationType="com.test.problemannotation"
      label="MyAnnotation"
      icon="icons/icon16x16.png"
      overviewRulerPreferenceKey="clruler"
      overviewRulerPreferenceValue="true"
      colorPreferenceKey="clcolor"
      colorPreferenceValue="255,0,0"
      textPreferenceKey="cltext"
      textPreferenceValue="true"
      verticalRulerPreferenceKey="clvertical"
      verticalRulerPreferenceValue="true"
      textStylePreferenceKey="clstyle"
      textStylePreferenceValue="UNDERLINE"
      presentationLayer="4">
    </specification>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
    <type
        markerSeverity="2"
        super="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.error"
        name="com.test.problemannotation"
        markerType="com.test.problemmarker"/>
</extension>
```

The custom text editor inherits from `TextEditor` and the reconciler is a `MonoReconciler`. Seems like a pretty standard setup, when I look at existing editor / reconciler implementations. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you set up an Annotation Model? Probably one extending `AbstractMarkerAnnotationModel`

Comment: Thanks. I found another solution (see below). I use  `FileDocumentProvider` as my document provider base class. This class creates a `ResourceMarkerAnnotationModel` by default. It all seems to work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was able to fix it myself. The problem was, that I set my own preference store in the constructor of the `TextEditor` subclass:

```
setPreferenceStore(MyPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
```

I set a few breakpoints in the `AnnotationPainter` class and realized that all
annotations were disabled. When I removed this line from the editor, the annotations appeared.

I also noticed that it is sufficient to just create a marker. A corresponding annotation will be added automatically.